# Select option contains not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var str = "one man"
 $('#select option:contains("+str+")').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

is not working 
for my select box:

```
<select multiple id ="select">
   <option value="3">one man</option>
   <option value="4">second</option>
</select>
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

quote mismatch

```
var str = "one man";

$('#select option:contains('+str+')').prop('selected', true);
```

or you could just do:

```
$('#select').val(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the correct quotes (and `prop()`):

```
 $('#select option:contains('+str+')').prop('selected', true);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/V85Vx/)**

Answer (score 0):

Typo quote mismatch

```
$('#select option:contains("'+str+'")').prop('selected', 'selected');
                string      ^ var ^   string //added single quote
```

---

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)